# Present excel formula in VBA format

Tags: excel, vba

How do I write the below formula in VBA format?  I've tried so many options, but they all give compile errors.

```
=COUNTFS(A2:A9,="2013",B2:B9,="Bikes")
```

Comment: 1. there is a typo, 2. please show what you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

Excel Formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,"2013",B2:B9,"Bikes")
```

in VBA:

```
Dim count As Integer
count = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A2:A9"), "2013", Range("B2:B9"), "Bikes")
```

Hope you looking for this?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is use a correct formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9=2013)*(B2:B9="Bikes"))
```

and in **VBA,** we must double-up on the double-quotes!:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String
    s = "=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9=2013)*(B2:B9=""Bikes""))"
    MsgBox Evaluate(s)

    Range("C1").Formula = s
End Sub
```